ACCESS vba Error 3044, ¿qué solución tengo?
lo primero gracias por dejarme formar parte de esto.
Tengo el siguiente código en vba y me da el error 3044 ruta no valida, la base de datos realmente si esta en esa ruta, he realizado cambios de ruta poniéndola en c: y me sigue dando el error, no se que hacer ya. El tema es que tengo varias bases de datos en dbf con las cuales están trabajando y estoy creando una aplicación en ACCESS para que sea más cómodo, lo que estoy intentando con el código es crear y/o actualizar una tabla en access que contenga esos datos para ir haciendo pruebas mientras esta terminada la aplicación.
El código que utilizo es el siguiente:
Sub CrearTablaDesdeDBF_Click()
  
 Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
    Dim rstDBF As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim strDBFPath As String
    Dim strTableName As String
    Dim i As Integer
    
    ' Ruta de acceso al archivo DBF
    strDBFPath = "i:\Ancianos\Asociacion.dbf"
      ' Nombre de la tabla en Access
    strTableName = "prb"
    
    ' Abre la base de datos de Access
    Set db = CurrentDb
    
    ' Comprueba si la tabla ya existe en la base de datos de Access
    For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
        If tdf.Name = strTableName Then
            ' La tabla ya existe, elimínala
            db.TableDefs.Delete strTableName
            Exit For
        End If
    Next tdf
    
    ' Crea la tabla en Access con la misma estructura que el archivo DBF
    Set tdf = db.CreateTableDef(strTableName)
    Set rstDBF = OpenRecordsetFromDBF(strDBFPath)
    
    ' Agrega los campos a la tabla en Access
    For i = 0 To rstDBF.Fields.Count - 1
        With rstDBF.Fields(i)
            tdf.Fields.Append tdf.CreateField(!Name, !Type, !Size)
        End With
    Next i
    
    ' Agrega la tabla a la base de datos de Access
    db.TableDefs.Append tdf
    
    ' Inserta los datos del archivo DBF en la tabla de Access
    Do While Not rstDBF.EOF
        strSQL = "INSERT INTO " & strTableName & " VALUES ("
        For i = 0 To rstDBF.Fields.Count - 1
            strSQL = strSQL & "'" & rstDBF.Fields(i).Value & "', "
        Next i
        strSQL = Left(strSQL, Len(strSQL) - 2) & ")"
        db.Execute strSQL
        rstDBF.MoveNext
    Loop
    
    ' Cierra las conexiones y objetos
    rstDBF.Close
    Set rstDBF = Nothing
    Set tdf = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    
    MsgBox "La tabla ha sido creada y actualizada correctamente.", vbInformation
End Sub

Function OpenRecordsetFromDBF(DBFPath As String) As DAO.Recordset
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    
    ' Abre la base de datos DBF
    Set db = OpenDatabase(DBFPath, False, False, "dBASE IV;")
    ' Abre el recordset desde la tabla DBF
    Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM NombreDeLaTablaEnElDBF", dbOpenSnapshot)
    
    ' Devuelve el recordset
    Set OpenRecordsetFromDBF = rst
  
End Function

Espero encontrar alguna solución.
Un saludo ............ Miguel

¿Qué linea da el error? ¿Comprobaste bien las rutas? Prueba a abrir la base manualmente y comprobar s tiene alguna tabla lincada a otras rutas diferentes a las que no tiene acceso. mas info aquí

La línea en la que me da el error es  strDBFPath = "i:\Ancianos\Asociacion.dbf" y la base de datos dbf esta en ese sitio

Lo que intento con este código es crear una tabla desde un archivo dbf y si ya existe actualizarla, el tema es que están trabajando con ese tipo de archivo y hasta que no este terminada toda la gestión que estoy haciendo, necesito importar los datos actualizados para realizar las diferentes pruebas. Si alguien sabe otra forma de realizarlo, sería de gran ayuda que me lo dijera.
